# MySQL Syntax Error on PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I get this error message:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id']; ?>'' at line 1

When running this code:

```
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (!$check1_res) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
    }

$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bordercolor="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong><?php echo $rows['topic']; ?></strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['detail']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>By :</strong> <?php echo $rows['name']; ?> <strong>Email : </strong><?php echo $rows['email'];?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/time : </strong><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
<BR>

<?php

$tbl_name2="forum_answer"; // Switch to table "forum_answer"
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result2=mysqli_query($con, $sql2)or die(mysql_error());
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){

?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Answer</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_answer']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table><br>

<?php
}

$sql3="SELECT view FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result3=mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result3);
$view=$rows['view'];

// if have no counter value set counter = 1
if(empty($view)){
$view=1;
$sql4="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(view) VALUES('$view') WHERE id='$id'";
$result4=mysqli_query($con, $sql4);
}

// count more value
$addview=$view+1;
$sql5="update $tbl_name set view='$addview' WHERE id='$id'";
$result5=mysqli_query($con, $sql5);
mysql_close();
?>

<BR>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="add_answer.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td width="18%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td width="3%">:</td>
<td width="79%"><input name="a_name" type="text" id="a_name" size="45"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="a_email" type="text" id="a_email" size="45"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><strong>Answer</strong></td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><textarea name="a_answer" cols="45" rows="3" id="a_answer"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can not figure this problem out. Need help. Thanks!

Comment: you can't use var for table name  ..

Comment: try to surround your $tbl_name with `\`` and see if that fixes it

Comment: `id']; ?>''` is really in the error message?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: do you mean `.$tbl_name.`

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. WHERE id=''' at line 1.

Comment: I got that message now when i did .$tbl_name.

Comment: I think the problem is in your form. It's sending PHP code as the value of the `id` input.

Comment: `$tbl_name` probably doesn't have value seeing `right syntax to use near '. WHERE` or there's something funky happening with that variable.

Comment: Use `View Source` to look at the page with the form, it probably has something like `value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"` in it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why would that cause an error near `'id']; ?>''`?

Comment: Post your html form

Comment: @Barmar [This comment by the OP...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264261/trouble-with-a-query-the-message-is-as-shown-below#comment73597143_43264261) shows a different message.

Comment: I suspect you've made the common mistake of trying to use `<?php echo` inside a string.

Comment: Post full code.

Comment: `if (!$check1_res)` that does nothing. You most likely meant `$result` unless that's not your full/real code. Too many unknowns in this question.

Comment: I can send the entire code if that will be easier for you

Comment: The variable chek1res does not exist. But the error should be from your html form. Check your value attribute.  Probably the php tag wasn't closed or wasn't opened

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name." WHERE id='".$id."'"; then do a echo $sql; to see if the query is correct.

Comment: I got this output: SELECT * FROM forum_questions WHERE id=''

Comment: Yes you can @scaisEdge. You just cannot use a prepared statement for table and column names.

Comment: The id is blank - that is why you're getting an error. `$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';` What URL are you using to access this code? Or, are you using a form where the `method="get"` or doesn't have a method at all? Add your form markup to the question.

Comment: I posted the entire code now in the question

Comment: I got the db connection in the beginning

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` and `mysql_error()` - do not intermix with the `mysqli_` connection you established; that is partly why your code is failing. You should have posted your entire code from the beginning. You've been given an answer now, see that. @DanielSmith

Comment: then there's `INSERT INTO $tbl_name(view) VALUES('$view') WHERE id='$id'` - INSERT does not use a WHERE clause, that too is failing. Same goes for a similar query. And did you not open your code with `<?php` ?

Comment: @Barmar ^ 2 comments. Seen their edit also? In case you're interested that is.

Comment: The HTML is invalid. You can't have `<form>` directly inside `<tr>`. The children of `<tr>` have to be `<td>` or `<th>`

Comment: You should have the `<form>` around the whole `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you were getting an error resulting in sql injection and or that you were using single quotes around an integer. To safeguard against sql injection the best way is to use prepared statements, however prepared statements only work for fields, so the best practice when dynamically changing table names in a query is use a white list where you are checking a value against a white list and setting the table with a static value to prevent injection. Also it's ideal to validate `$_GET` and `$_POST` values using `filter_input`.

```
$id=filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($id === false) {
    //filter failed
    die('id not a number');
}
if ($id === null) {
    //variable was not set
    die('id not set');
}

//white list table 
$safe_tbl_name = '';
switch($tbl_name){
    case 'Table1': 
        $safe_tbl_name = 'MyTable1';
        break;
    case 'Table2':
        $safe_tbl_name = 'MyTable2';
        break;
    default:
        $safe_tbl_name = 'MyDataTable';
};

$sql="SELECT * FROM `$safe_tbl_name` WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
if (!$check1_res) {
     printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
     exit();
}

$rows = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

**EDIT**

Also worth noting, you're using `mysqli` however you've used the following `mysql` functions that should be changed to their `mysqli` counter parts.

```
mysql_close()
mysql_error()
mysql_fetch_array()
```

**EDIT**

As @Barmar noted you're creating invalid HTML, I would strongly recommend running your output page through the [W3C HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and correcting issue.

Comment: Yep that is great all errors are gone now, thanks a lot :D I got the output id not a number